# Java 8 - Find Leaders in an Array

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I am trying to learn the features of Java 8 especially the functional programming aspect of it. So I am trying to solve a problem: Find Leaders in an Array - A leader is an element which is larger than all the elements in the array to its right.

For example:

Input Array:
{ 98, 23, 54, 12, 20, 7, 27 }

Output:
Leaders - 27 54 98

Now, I have solved this using the usual iterative approach as shown below.

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
        int currentLeader = array[array.length - 1];
        System.out.println(currentLeader);
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(array[i] > currentLeader) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
                currentLeader = array[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried solving it using Java 8, but I couldn't do much apart from writing this piece of code, which again had compilation error:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> checkLeader = i ->  i > currentLeader ? i : currentLeader;
```

> Error: Local variable currentLeader defined in an enclosing scope must
>   be final or effectively final

Now how do I solve the same problem using the features of Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional, imperative approach seems the best one to me, both taking performance and readability/ease of maintenance into account. Nonetheless, here's my attempt using streams and a little bit of functional programming:

```
List<Integer> leaders = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> array[array.length - i])
    .collect(toLeaders());
```

Here I'm creating a `1..n` closed range and then, within `mapToObj`, converting index `1` to `n - 1`, index `2` to `n - 2`, and so on. I immediately use this converted index to get the corresponding element of the array, which is finally collected to a list with the assistance of a custom collector. This custom collector is returned by the `toLeaders()` helper method:

```
private static Collector<Integer, ?, List<Integer>> toLeaders() {
    BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> accumulator = (leaders, n) -> { 
        if (leaders.isEmpty() || n > leaders.get(leaders.size() - 1)) { 
            leaders.add(n);
        }
    };
    return Collector.of(ArrayList::new, accumulator, (leaders1, leaders2) -> {
        leaders2.forEach(n -> accumulator.accept(leaders1, n));
        return leaders1;
    });
}
```

The `BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> accumulator` accepts two values: a list containing the leaders found so far, and an element from the stream. This [`Biconsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html) checks if the given number is a leader and if the check succeeds, adds the number to the given list of leaders.

Then, a collector that uses this accumulator is created by means of the [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) utility, which also accepts a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) of the mutable structure that will hold the leaders (this is `ArrayList::new`) and a [`BinaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) combiner that is in charge of merging two list of leaders that were created previously (this is to be used only when the stream is parallel). This combiner uses the previously declared  `accumulator` biconsumer.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the answer. Java 8 seems to be a new language altogether. So much to learn...

Answer (score 3):

How about this? you can using [IntBinaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html) instead of `Function<Integer, Integer>` since `checkLeader` is not an **effectively-final** variable so it can't be accessed in a lambda expression, but you can pass `checkLeader` as parameters into a lambda expression:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    IntBinaryOperator checkLeader = (left, right) -> left > right ? left : right;

    int currentLeader = array[array.length - 1];
    System.out.println(currentLeader);
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //  pass `currentLeader` for each call ---v
        if (checkLeader.applyAsInt(array[i], currentLeader) == array[i]) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            currentLeader = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

### Let's refactoring it step by step to using stream api

**First**, using [IntBinaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html) can't know whether `checkLeader` is less than `array[i]` since it returns the final larger result (when `checkLeader` == `array[i]` then program has bugs). so you need a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) rather than a [IntBinaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html):

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compareTo;

    int currentLeader = array[array.length - 1];
    System.out.println(currentLeader);
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //  check whether array[i] > currentLeader   ---v
        if (comparator.compare(array[i], currentLeader) > 0) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            currentLeader = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Then** we can using [Comparator#nullsFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) to remove the first `println` statement since it is duplicated in loop:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);

    Integer currentLeader = null;
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //  array[0] is always > currentLeader since it is null at the first time
        //                                              |
        if (comparator.compare(array[i], currentLeader) > 0) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            currentLeader = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Prepare** to using stream-api we need separates display logic from  collecting logic by using a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) :

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(null);

    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //  comparing array[i] with the top leaders ---v
        if (comparator.compare(array[i], stack.peek()) > 0) {
            stack.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

//take 1st element away from stack since it is just a initial value for comparision
    //                               |
    System.out.println(stack.subList(1, stack.size()));
}
```

**Using** [IntStream#range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to **reverse** the array, then we can using `for-each` loop instead:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    stack.push(null);

    int[] reversed = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
            //      v--- reverse array elements
            .map(i -> array[array.length - i - 1]).toArray();

    for (int candidate : reversed) {
        if (comparator.compare(candidate, stack.peek()) > 0) {
            stack.push(candidate);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(stack.subList(1, stack.size()));
}
```

**Then** we can inline all statements in one line except `comparator`  by using [IntStream#collect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-), but wait, an error is thrown by `Stack#peek` since the stack is empty:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);

    List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
            .map(i -> array[array.length - i - 1])
            .collect(
                    Stack::new,
                    (stack, candidate) -> {
                        // failed at the first time since the stack is empty
                        //                                     |
                        if (comparator.compare(candidate, stack.peek()) > 0) {
                            stack.push(candidate);
                        }
                    },
                    Stack::addAll
            );

    System.out.println(result.subList(1, result.size()));
}
```

**Fix** the error by checking whether the stack is empty or not:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> c = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);

    List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
        .map(i -> array[array.length - i - 1])
        .collect(
            Stack::new,
            (stack, candidate) -> {
                //        v-- just add 1st candidate when stack is empty
                if (stack.isEmpty() || c.compare(candidate, stack.peek()) > 0) {
                    stack.push(candidate);
                }
            },
            Stack::addAll
        );

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Finally** we can using ternary-operator `?:` to inline the lambda expression body:

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Integer::compareTo);

    List<Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
        .map(i -> array[array.length - i - 1])
        .collect(
            Stack::new,
            (stack, candidate) -> stack.push(
               stack.isEmpty() || comparator.compare(candidate, stack.peek()) > 0 ?
                            candidate :
                            stack.pop()
            ),
            Stack::addAll
        );

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

### Edit

Thanks for @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner to audit my answer, `Comparator#nullsFirst` is unnecessary now since the code never push a `null` initial value for comparision.

```
private static void findLeaders(int[] array) {
    Comparator<Integer> comparator = Integer::compareTo;

    List<Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, array.length)
        .map(i -> array[array.length - i])
        .collect(
            Stack::new,
            (stack, candidate) -> stack.push(
              stack.isEmpty() || comparator.compare(candidate, stack.peek()) > 0 ?
                 candidate :
                 stack.pop()
                 //    ^--- just push the top back to the stack if top<=candidate
            ),
            Stack::addAll
        );

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer.

Comment: @RahulDevMishra Not at all. it's my pleasure.